# auto increment named ranges in Excel

Tags: excel, named-ranges

[Named Range][1]

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GFYE.jpg

As you can see in above pic I am trying to create named range for last 3 months,
With next refresh latest month's column will be added. 
my que is when that happens I still want my named range to show last 3 columns. So can any1 tell me how it can be done.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what do you expect as answer: a method explaining how you can do it manually ... wrong place ... a (VBA) code for automatic execution ...  show some efforts/what have you tried sofar/what worked and what didn't ... otherwise the quickest answer will be: yes it can be done, manually delete and recreate the named range

Comment: I am new to excel and I don't want vba code for it. just plain formula can work, if it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Create a named range for those entire three rows (starting at the first column of the table), or for those three rows as far as you think it could ever extend. Call it FullTable or something.

Step 2: Create a helper cell. Put in it `=COUNTIF(INDEX(FullTable,1,0),"<>"&"")`. Name it TableCols.

Step 3: The formula for the named range you want is `=INDEX(FullTable,1,TableCols-2):INDEX(FullTable,3,TableCols)`